# Check my idea on signer

Tags: solidity, dapps

I want to confirm my idea about signer, this is what i know:
**Singer is who signs a transaction in mark of acceptance the transaction. When A wants to transact he attaches a signature with the transaction, the signature is basically the hash of transaction data + private key. We can use this signature in ecrecover to get the address of A.**
Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed. The **signer of a transaction** is the address/person who **created the signature** and is **attached to the tx data**. The signature itself is created by **combining the tx data with the signers private key**. This then **generates a unique hash**, and this hash can be verified with the **signers public key**.

To recover the address of the signer from the tx data and the signature, the `ecreover` function is used - with this we can verify that the tx has been signed by the person who says to have signed it.

#### Summary

**Signer:** person/address who signs a tx by creating a signature using the private key.

**Signature:** used to verify the signer and the integrity of the tx data.